# Node.js Unit Testing - Create Mock Layer Using mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have written a web service that indeed consumes an external web service, after performing some validations and data manipulations (plain business logic). I need to write unit tests for the same and need to have code coverage report as well. Many suggestions are available on the net, Mocha being the prominent one. But in all available examples, actual DB call or external service call happens. My requirement is not to have actual external service call, but just mock the call (Just how, we do using EasyMock in Java). Any help would be highly appreciated. Is it possible to create a mock of DB call or external service call in node js ?

Comment: For mongodb, there is one module https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-mock for test

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sinon with Mocha to provide stubbing, or spying of calls.  It is important to also write you code to aid mocking.  For instance, don't assume the database handler exists in the web component, pass it in through the constructor.  That way its easy for testing to replace the database with your own "mocked" version.

As an example - here is the start of one of my bunch of tests where I instanciate a mocked connection pool to my database handler and pass it into the test. I am actually also mocking the web server, and just testing the API.

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  const DBHOST = 'dummy';
  const DBNAME = 'dummy';


  const expect = require('chai').expect;
  const sinon = require('sinon');


  const mock = require('../mock/server');
  const DB = require('../database');
  const Logging = require('../log');
  Logging.debug(true); //set to log debug message
  const logger = Logging.logger;
  const poolPromise = mock.getPool();
  const db = new DB(mock.Pool,DBNAME,logger);

  const API = require('../api');
  const api = new API(mock.server,db,logger);




  describe('API tests',function() {
    let sandbox, testConnection;
    beforeEach(function(){
      sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
      testConnection = new mock.Connection();
      return poolPromise.then(pool => {
        pool.getConnection().then(cb => {
          cb(null,testConnection);
        });
      });

    });
    afterEach(function(){
      sandbox.restore();
    });

    describe('/logon',function() {
      let params;
      describe('Admin', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
          params = {name: 'Admin', password: 'abcde'};
        })
        it('Performs logon if username is "Admin" and password is good', function(done) {
          mock.server.emit('/logon', params, (status,user) => {
            expect(status).to.be.true;
            expect(user).to.be.an('object');
            expect(user.uid).to.be.equal(0);
            expect(user.name).to.be.equal('Super User');
            expect(user.keys).to.be.equal('A');
            done();
          });
          testConnection.next.then(value => {
            let request = value.request;
            expect(value.name).to.equal('execSql');
            expect(request.sqlTextOrProcedure).to.equal('SELECT passwordsalt FROM Admin WHERE AdminID = 0');
            request.emit('row', mock.makeRow('passwordsalt',['salt']));
            request.callback(null,1);
            return testConnection.next;
          }).then(value => {
            let request = value.request
            expect(value.name).to.equal('callProcedure');
            expect(request.sqlTextOrProcedure).to.equal('CheckPassword');
            request.emit('row',mock.makeRow('a',[1]));
            request.callback(null,0);
          });
        });
```